# How to erase space above menu bar? Or just erase "first row" entirely

Tags: menus, custom-background

Summary: The space above the menu and at the end of the website cannot be erased. I use theme Blocksy. Now the menu is not attached to the top.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOGAj.png)

Question: Do you know how to erase this background space?

Comment: I have found the answer myself in the end! Jeeejjjj. 
Customizer > upper row > turn off "show empty space"

Comment: Glad to hear! This sort of question is considered off-topic and not in this stack's scope for future reference, as it either isn't related to WordPress specifically, or has to do with third-party themes.